# Cannot connect to Redis server on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, redis, bitnami

I have a rails application deployed on google app engine. I visit `myapp.com/resque` with a local redis server running and it works. When doing this in production, I cant seem to connect. I have a redis vm instance deployed on google compute engine and I cannot `redis-cli -h 123.123.123:6379` into it on any of the servers. It only returns `Could not connect to Redis at 11.111.11.1:6379: Connection refused`. I've tried using both the internal and external IPs and no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. 
It was due to bind in redis conf. By default redis was binded to only 127.0.0.1
It's in redis.conf file
bind 127.0.0.1
As mentioned in redis security [link](http://redis.io/topics/security) its there so that only trusted clients are allowed to connect and by default its only localhost